# Openpyxl iterating through cells, can't compare cells to string

Tags: python, excel, datetime, openpyxl

I am having issues iterating through every cell in a workbook and comparing the call's value to a string object.  I am able to successfully compare to datetime objects in the workbook but when it comes to regular 'String' objects nothing is being printed, and the cells are not updating.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pathz, read_only=False)
ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == a:
                print("Found datetime cell")
                cell.value = newDate

            if cell.value == "Hello":
                print("Found string cell")
                cell.value = "Goodbye"

wb.save(pathz)
```

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what is happening without seeing the data in your spreadsheet. What happens if you add `print(cell.value)` inside the for loop?

Comment: it prints the proper cell.value

Comment: furthermore, when I try to do an if cell.value == 'String' PythonWin gives me an encoding error and won't let me save until I remove the 'String' part.

Comment: That error helps. What do you get for `print(cell.encoding)`? Also, which version of Python are you using (2 or 3)?

Comment: I am using python 3.6, I get 'utf-8' when i print(cell.encoding)

Comment: I've tried, but I just can't reproduce your problem. In an attempt to help you, I've posted code that works for me as an answer. If this code also works for you, then there must be something about the contents of the cells in your file (like extra whitespace) that is causing the match to fail.

Comment: let me try the second half of yours right now. thank you craig

Comment: @Craig, yep, yours works. i'm not sure whats wrong with mine. if it is the whitespace issue, how can i solve it?

Comment: @Craig, the encoding problem has seized on its own it seems

Comment: There is no whitespace problem, alhtough something I did notice is that the dash when i open the excel looks different than a normal "-" it looked more like a "--" without the space in between the two dashes....can this be an issue?

Comment: Yes! It could be using an unicode dash. You should be able to copy the cell contents from Excel and paste it into your program to get the correct character.

Comment: @Craig let's give it a try! one second ill keep you posted

Comment: @Craig, ok so when I paste the unicode dash into my python ide, it gives me the encoding error if I try to save it. looks like that's the problem

Comment: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 6725: ordinal not in range(256). Please add desired source encoding as first line of file, eg #--coding: mbcs-- –

Comment: @Craig looks the dash is precisly the problem, how does one go about fixing it? I am not able to save my file with the new dash in my code right now due to the encoding issue

Comment: Using `utf-8` as the encoding works for me. Add this line as the _first_ or _second_ line in your file: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to change the coding for the file.

Comment: @Craig, to the first line of my .py file right? sorry newb

Comment: Yes. First line of the `.py` file. I'll add this to my answer also.

Comment: Ok so it works when i compare directly to string that was copy and pasted from excel.  I am confused why when I past just the dash from excel and use it join two strings together that it no longer works?

Comment: I don't know why joining strings with that character doesn't work, you should post that as a new question.

Comment: If my answers have been helpful, you can thank me by doing two things: 1) upvote the answer (up triangle) and 2) accept the answer by selecting the gray checkmark. I'd appreciate it if you also do this for the question I helped you with yesterday.

Comment: @Craig thank you so much man.  I'll look into what's going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to read and write dates and strings to an Excel formatted file without problems. The code below shows this working for both types of cell contents.

The string that the OP was trying to match contained a unicode dash character `'\u2013'`, which doesn't match with the ASCII `'-'` character, so the strings weren't matching. The strings in the example below use this unicode dash character.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import openpyxl
import datetime

#create a workbook containing a string and save it
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1)
ws['A2'] = '4/1/2017–4/30/2017' # The dash between the dates is '\u2013'
wb.save('Test.xlsx')

#open that workbook and read it
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Test.xlsx', read_only=False)
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        print('Cell: [{}] is type({}): "{}"'.format(cell.coordinate, type(cell.value).__name__, cell.value))
        if cell.value == '4/1/2017–4/30/2017':
            print('Found "4/1/2017–4/30/2017"')
```

Running this on Python 3.6 produces this output:

```
Cell: [A1] is type(datetime): "2017-04-01 00:00:00"
Cell: [A2] is type(str): "4/1/2017–4/30/2017"
Found "4/1/2017–4/30/2017"
```

Comment: I do not understand why it does not work for me then, this is confusing

Comment: @Alex Try running the second half of my code on your file (the half that reads the data) and let me know what it prints for the line with the string that you want to match.

Comment: it did not produce anything even though i know there are multiple instances of the string in the excel sheet.