# How to find all cells in a work book that contain strings that look like 'TK005'?

Tags: python, excel, string, openpyxl

Note that the first two letters of the string may be any set of two letters, the last the characters of the string however are always numbers.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if str(cell.value) == #something like 'XX008':
            print(cell.value)
```

Comment: Please stop submitting what is essentially the same question again and again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openpyxl iterating through cells, can't compare cells to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711327/openpyxl-iterating-through-cells-cant-compare-cells-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if re.search('\w\w\d\d\d', cell.value):
            print(cell.value)
```

This should work. You can also condense the `'\w\w\d\d\d'` string if you want, but if you know your string is always 2 word characters followed by 3 digits, then you're good.

**Edit:**
I might as well show you a better regex string to use since I have time.

```
'[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}'
```

This regex string is even better than the one I originally gave you. \w is a special character in regex strings that will match any word character. That means `[a-zA-Z0-9]` \d will match just `[0-9]`. In order to be more specific, I specify a range of only alphabetical characters in place of \w.

As for the {2} and {3}, it means "match me 2 of the characters/range of characters that precede" So you will get 2 characters A-Z or a-z followed by 3 digits 0-9.

Comment: I editted my answer as to add a better regex string to use. You can check out this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) or the Python docs to see more examples. Knowing regex is very useful.

Comment: Thank you sir for your time and commitment to helping me, as soon as I complete one part of my code I will be able to test yours and put it into use.

Comment: Tell me how it goes. If you want, I can give you another good link on Regular Expressions in general.

Comment: with your new regex string, would I use it liek so? if re.search('[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}', cell.value):

Comment: The new regex string you used works a charm! first one was not specific enough and would find cells that are not actually what I am looking for, this one works great tho